# How do I redirect data from a pipe to another in c?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to write from one process to the another using two separate pipes. In the following manner:

1. child1 writes to parent (using pipe1)
2. parent writes to child2  (using pipe2)

I have no problems writing to the parent, but when I try to relay the data to child2, the file descriptor appears to be NULL and I'm not sure why. For clarity purposes, I tried to emboldened the areas that I am having problems with. I also removed a lot of the error handling.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
  {
      pid_t pid;
      pid_t pid1;
      int mypipe[2];
      int mypipe1[2];
      int file;
      char buf[100];
      FILE *stream;
      FILE *stream2;
      FILE *rm;
      ssize_t numbersread;

          if (pipe (mypipe))
            {
              fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
              return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
          if (pipe (mypipe1))
            {
              fprintf (stderr, "Pipe2 failed.\n");
              return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

          /* CREATE THE FIRST CHILD HERE. */
          pid = fork ();

          if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
            {
                rm = fopen("Readme.txt","r");

                //10 BYTES AT A TIME
                close(mypipe[0]);
                for(k=0;k<=10;k++)
                {
                  transmitor(mypipe[1],rm); // GO READ FILE AND THEN WRITE ON PIPE
                }
                fclose(rm);

                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }


          // BACK TO THE PARENT PROCESS
          else
            {
            /*OBJECTIVES:
                1. READ THE FILE FROM THE PIPE
                2. WRITE THE FILE ONTO A SECOND PIPE
                3.SEND IT TO THE RECEIVER
            */

             FILE *file1;
             ssize_t numbersread1;
             file1 = fdopen(mypipe[0],"r");

             close (mypipe[1]);
             close(mypipe1[0]);
             stream2 = fdopen(mypipe1[1],"w");
             while(!feof(file1)){
              numbersread1 = fread(buf, 1, (sizeof buf),file1);
              printf("%zd\n", numbersread1);
              **fwrite(buf,1,numbersread1,stream2);**
              buf[numbersread1] = 0;
             }
             printf("%s\n","finished parent");
             fclose(file1);// FINISHED READING
             fclose(stream2);

           ** /* CREATE THE SECOND CHILD HERE #2. */
            /*OBJECTIVES:
               1. READ DATA FROM PIPE
               2. WRITE DATA TO FILE*/

             pid1 = fork ();
             sleep(2);
             if (pid1 == (pid_t) 0)
                {
                  /* This is the child process.
                     Close read end first. */
                     FILE *stream3;
                     stream3 = fdopen(mypipe1[0],"r");
                     close (mypipe1[1]);
                    if(stream3==NULL)
                     {
                      printf("%s","NULL Stream3 Variable");
                     }
                    else
                     {
                      while (!feof(stream3)) {
                      printf("\r\nIN WHILE\r\n");
                      numbersread = fread(buf, 1, (sizeof buf),stream3);
                      printf("%zd\n", numbersread);
                      buf[numbersread] = 0;
                    }
                     fclose(stream3);
                    }**

                    printf("%s","FINISHED RECEIVER");

                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }


             return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }// THIS CLOSES THE FIRST ENTRANCE TO THE PARENT PROCESS WHERE WE ARE WRITING TO THE FIRST RECEIVER



        }// THIS IS THE END OF THE MAIN FUNCTION
```

Comment: Is there more code?  This code can't possible work alone.  It never calls [`pipe()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) to create a pipe.  Creating a variable with `int mypipe[2];` only creates a variable that is an array holding  two ints.  To get a pipe, you have to pass that array to `pipe()`.

Comment: I removed this part initially:   if (pipe (mypipe))
                {
                  fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
                  return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
              if (pipe (mypipe1))
                {
                  fprintf (stderr, "Pipe2 failed.\n");
                  return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

Comment: That looks OK. You shouldn't remove it.

Comment: See the example on http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe how to correctly use `pipe`, and then check if http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen isn't the better choice.

Comment: @user1774537 Is the error caused by removing that code?

Comment: @paul no error was caused when I removed that. Also I tried your earlier suggestion and I still got a null value for the "stream3" file descriptor on the second child.

Comment: I think you will find that removing the pipe code and recompiling the program will break all the communications, since it is what creates the pipes.  Johannes seems to have an answer about stream3.

Comment: Excuse me Paul! you were 100% correct, I was making a very silly mistake.  I created 2 versions of the code. The first one is the actual code with all the functions, and error detection, and the second one, an overly simplified version so that my post is easier to understand; Long story short, I was compiling the wrong version. Johannes solution worked, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `close(2)` file descriptors you use later, for example this bit of your code:

```
file1 = fdopen(mypipe[0],"r");

close (mypipe[1]);
close(mypipe1[0]);
```

you close `mypipe1[0]`. Further down you do:

```
FILE *stream3;
stream3 = fdopen(mypipe1[0],"r");
close (mypipe1[1]);
```

therefore `stream3` will be `NULL`.

I would also strongly recommend to name the variables a bit more what they do. For example `mypipe` could be `c1_to_parent` and `mypipe1` could be `parent_to_c2`. That would make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: You were correct that was the problem. Thanks a million!